# Htc Desire won't recognize that it's usb connected

Tags: usb-drive, android

I'm trying to debug on my htc desire. When I connect my phone through USB the phone starts charging as normal but it won't recognize that it is connected to the pc.

Normally I can find the usb debugging mode in my notification bar for example and it's not there and I don't event get the option to mount as storage media etc.

Comment: please don't tell me my phone is broken a month after my warranty ended -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might sound stupid but try a different usb cable .. (I got one that can only charge my htc desire)
and check to see if it happens on another computer.. (also.. happen to me before)

Comment: I agree with @Joe. Some cables are not compatible withe composite USB port on the devices and generally just charge.

Answer (score 1):

If you're totally certain that the phone is in Development Mode (Settings --> Applications --> Development --> USB Debugging) then I'd reinstall the drivers for the phone. Sounds stupid, I know, but it actually worked for me when I couldn't debug on my Galaxy.

Rebooting the device is also *highly* recommended.

Hope this helps!